# How does one become a beekeeper?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

Alright so I read the beekeeping 101 on the Wiki for Forestry and really didn't feel like it gave me a good grasp on the subject. If anything it caused more confusion for me. Where should I start in-game for beekeeping?

Comment: Did the beehive break when you used the scoop?

Comment: Also, this seems more of a "give me a walkthrough or how-to guide to beekeeping" than a narrow question that we can usefully answer in this format. Consider narrowing it down and breaking it into separate specific questions you would like to resolve.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie no it didnt break, and i narrowed it down to just where to start in beekeeping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Beekeeping 101](http://forestry.sengir.net/wiki.new/doku.php?id=bees:intro) – the "101" course – is really just a teaser to pique your curiosity and get you to experiment with the items and blocks. The intention is that you'll start, and learn by trial and error. It doesn't teach you how to do much, so much as it gives a broad survey of beekeeping.

In practical terms, start by collecting bees. Craft a [scoop](http://forestry.sengir.net/wiki.new/doku.php?id=bees:tools) and go find some wild beehives. Break the hive with the scoop (just like mining with a pick, it takes a few seconds of concentrated beatings) and it should drop bees, along with other random drops related to the type of hive it is, like various types of honeycomb.

Take your bees back home. Put them in a chest if you're not ready to set up apiaries (artificial hives) – they'll be perfectly happy stored with your other junk until you're ready to deal with them.

When you've got an apiary built (for your first one, make sure it has flowers nearby and can see the sky directly above) and are ready to become a bee-*keeper* rather than merely a collector, select one princess and one drone and put them into the apiary. They'll breed and the princess will become a queen bee, producing honey and eventually new young bees, before dying. You've begun your journey into beekeeping.

By selectively breeding your princesses and drones you can cross-breed your bees and select for desirable genetic traits, using a [beealyzer](http://forestry.sengir.net/wiki.new/doku.php?id=bees:tools:beealyzer) to help you – but that's not getting started, that's the long journey of becoming an expert beekeeper.

Comment: I have a couple apiarys I stole from a village and 2 queen bees. But I guess the environment is to hostile for them. Are bees environment specific to the biomes u find them in?

Comment: @Paralytic Yes. They can tolerate some variation in environment, but wild bees can't tolerate much. See this Q&A for how much variation there can be among bees: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/113290/what-is-the-bee-genetic-heirarchy